# Passing Variables Between Two Functions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Here is the relevant code:

```
func touchLocationAngle() {
        func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch in touches{
                var touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
                var angle1 = atan2(1SpriteNode.position.y - touchLocation.y , 1SpriteNode.position.x - touchLocation.x)
                var angle = angle1 - CGFloat(Double.pi / 1)
            }
        }
    }

    func moveToTouchLocation() {

    }
```

I  want to take the angle variable from the first function and use in the second. I don't want to make the variable global. I've looked at google and youtube but whenever I use their code it shows errors.

Comment: Your `touchesBegan` function is even on the wrong level. Delegate methods must be on the top level of the class.

Comment: You should really learn about function parameters. More generally, I recommend all Swift programmers read the Swift langauge guide, through and through. You won't believe how much more hardship you're going to encounter by tryign to work around not knowing these basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of things, I can edit my answer as needed, but what is the objective of the first function? From what I can tell, it's a function, that encompasses another function, that goes through the touches. But I also noticed that `angle` also gets overwritten every loop cycle, leaving you with the angle of only the last touch. My answer is a stab at what I think you want, but please clarify if  it isn't.

You'll want to return the angle in the first function, currently the first function does not have a return value. Then you'll want to call the first function, and pass along the value to the second eg, something like this

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        var touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        var angle1 = atan2(1SpriteNode.position.y - touchLocation.y , 1SpriteNode.position.x - touchLocation.x)
        var angle = angle1 - CGFloat(Double.pi / 1)
        moveToTouchLocation(angle)
    }
}

func moveToTouchLocation(angle: CGFloat) {
    // whatever you want to do here.
}
```